# mechanize gives AttributeError: class HTMLForm has no attribute 'did_submit'

Tags: python, html, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am attempting to run search button in "https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&ars=royal_blue_bar" using mechanize but it shows me:

```
AttributeError: class HTMLForm has no attribute 'did_submit'
```

```
import mechanize
import sys
import os
import socks
import socket
import threading
import time
from mechanize import Browser

website = 'https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&ars=royal_blue_bar'
website_s = 'https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&ars=royal_blue_bar'


file = 'wordlist.txt'

with open(file,"r")as list:
    for line in list:
                word = line.strip()
                br = mechanize.Browser()
                br.set_handle_robots(False)     
                br.open(website)
        br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('id', None) == 'identify_yourself_flow')         
                br.form['email'] = word
        br.method = "post"
                if br.did_submit().geturl() == website_s:
                   print "This is not a  Target  ==>" +worg                 
                else:
                    print'This is a Target ==>'+word
```

I tested all methods but could not make it work.

Comment: Where did you find that `did_submit` method? There is nothing like that in the [docs](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=did_submit&check_keywords=yes&area=default) as well as in the [source code](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize/search?q=did_submit&unscoped_q=did_submit).

Comment: look for search button

Comment: <label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonNoText" id="did_submit" for="u_0_2"><input value="Search" name="did_submit" id="u_0_2" type="submit"></label>

Comment: but what i should to do ? please